# Extract Method recommendations tool

Tags: java, code-beautification

Is there a tool that searches code and makes recommendations for extracting method candidates with duplicated code? Here's a really contrived example:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ExtractMethod {
  public boolean mode;

  public String getFirst(List<String> one, List<String> two) {
    if(mode) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for(String elements : one) {
        sb.append(elements.charAt(0));
      }
      return sb.toString();
    } else {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for(String elements : two) {
        sb.append(elements.charAt(0));
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

If you select the duplicated lines in Eclipse, and select Extract Method, you get this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ExtractMethod {
  public boolean mode;

  public String getFirst(List<String> one, List<String> two) {
    if(mode) {
      return getFirstFromList(one);
    } else {
      return getFirstFromList(two);
    }
  }

  private String getFirstFromList(List<String> one) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String elements : one) {
      sb.append(elements.charAt(0));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Pretty great. Is there a tool that looks through a class and makes recommendations about good candidates for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Popular free open-source PMD code analyzer has a copy-paste detector [CPD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/cpd-usage.html) - it can find similar code fragments which are good candidates to "extract method" refactoring. It is cross-platform and can be run in any system that have JRE implemented. It also have a vast variety of plugins for popular build tools and IDEs like maven, eclipse, ant, etc.

Comment: Okay actually this is not what I'm looking for, as far as I can tell this just looks for exact matches, not "similar code"

Comment: Also it requires that the tile size be at least 25. It doesn't find any duplication in the example provided in the OP.

Comment: Take a look at configuration options like ignore literals, ignore identifiers etc. This tool isn't just exact match locator.

Comment: Minimal duplicate size is also configurable, AFAIK

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I downloaded the Eclipse integrated tool; I tried to lower the size but it wouldn't let me. Is it possible the Eclipse tool is behind trunk?

Comment: Don't know about eclipse, command line version would be something like `java net.sourceforge.pmd.cpd.CPD --minimum-tokens 10 --files /mysourcesdir`

Answer (score 1):

Our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/CloneDR) tool will do this, detecting clones across thousands of files.  You don't give it anything but the files; it determines the clones automatically.

A clone set is a set of code blocks that are deemed similar.  Often clone sets are just pairs, sometimes of thousands of lines, this happens when source files are copied en masse in the code base.  Remarkably, clone sets may have 3, 100, up to several hundred instances of similar code; usually the individual clone in the latter case is 4-10 lines and represents some idiom used everywhere in the code base (e.g., a string-to-number conversion routine).

Among the almost 10,000 clone sets it finds in the over 1MSLOC of code comprising a version of the Eclipse JDT,  it will find these two clones:

```
    this.declaringQualification = isCaseSensitive() ? declaringQualification:  CharOperation.toLowerCase(declaringQualification);
    this.declaringSimpleName = isCaseSensitive() ? declaringSimpleName:  CharOperation.toLowerCase(declaringSimpleName);
    this.typeQualification = isCaseSensitive() ? typeQualification:  CharOperation.toLowerCase(typeQualification);
```

and

```
    this.declaringQualification = isCaseSensitive() ? declaringQualification:  CharOperation.toLowerCase(declaringQualification);
    this.declaringSimpleName = isCaseSensitive() ? declaringSimpleName:  CharOperation.toLowerCase(declaringSimpleName);
    this.returnQualification = isCaseSensitive() ? returnQualification:  CharOperation.toLowerCase(returnQualification);
```

and suggest this parameterized abstraction (not quite a method, but pretty close:

```
this.declaringQualification = isCaseSensitive() ? declaringQualification: CharOperation.toLowerCase(declaringQualification);
this.declaringSimpleName = isCaseSensitive() ? declaringSimpleName: CharOperation.toLowerCase(declaringSimpleName);
this. [[#variable5a6b82a0]]= isCaseSensitive() ? [[#variable5a6b82a0]]: CharOperation.toLowerCase( [[#variable5a6b82a0]]);
```

Notice that it decided the code has only *one* parameter, not two.

It will find bigger expressions, even statements, as parameters; in the latter case, it effectively suggests that you need a lambda as a parameter.

You can control the size of a clone, how many parameters are allowed, and how similar the code chunks have to be to be considered clones.  On OP's contrived example in one file, with the right settings, it should detect the inner blocks as clones with a single parameter.   (Nobody runs examples that small in practice.)

(The site has many examples from many languages).

Comment: This is pretty cool, I'll have to take a look at it later. By the way, please don't create new tags that don't add to the question. See the [help center](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: "copy-paste-detection" is a widely known term for clone-detection tools.  (I always thought "clone detection" was a fine term, but the world seems to think otherwise).